# JSSIP issue in firefox, cannot attach the audio sream

Tags: firefox, audio, webrtc, jssip

I have an issue with firefox browser and using JSSIP as webrtc.
Any solution for this?

this is my code when trying to attach the stream audio to html

```
 if (this.callSession.direction === 'outgoing') {
        this.callSession.connection.addEventListener('addstream', (addstreamEvent: any) => {
          this.remoteAudio.autoplay = true;
          this.remoteAudio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
          this.remoteAudio.srcObject = addstreamEvent.stream;
          logger.debug('outgoing callSession addstream');
        });
      }
```